# how to build grpc to static link library on macOS

Tags: macos, openssl, clang, homebrew, grpc

I want to build grpc to static link library on macOS,my macOS system is macOS Monterey version 12.6(Intel chip).

I found https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md#building-with-cmake build shared libraries that is Dynamic-link library，but I want to get static-link library.

gcc version is

```
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro lib % gcc --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro lib %
```

My ~/.zshrc config is

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mindgood/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH 
export ANDROID_NDK=/Users/mindgood/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"
export CPATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include:"${CPATH}"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig:"${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib:"${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

I have installed openssl.

```
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro ~ % openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022)
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro ~ % whereis opnessl
opnessl:
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro ~ % find / -name 'openssl'
/usr/bin/openssl
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
/usr/local/bin/openssl
/usr/local/include/openssl
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.5/bin/openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.5/include/openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.5/share/doc/openssl
/usr/local/share/doc/openssl
find: /Library/Application Support/Apple/ParentalControls/Users: Permission denied
find: /Library/Application Support/Apple/AssetCache/Data: Permission denied
find: /Library/Application Support/ApplePushService: Permission denied
find: /Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC: Operation not permitted
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/openssl
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/openssl
^C
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro ~ % 
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd /usr/local/lib 
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro lib % ls
engines-1.1     libcrypto.3.dylib   libcrypto.dylib     libssl.3.dylib      libssl.dylib
libcrypto.1.1.dylib libcrypto.a     libssl.1.1.dylib    libssl.a        pkgconfig
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro lib %
```

then I use below command:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.30.0 https://github.com/grpc/grpc 

cd grpc

git checkout -b v1.22.x remotes/origin/v1.22.x 

cmake ../grpc -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_NDK}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DgRPC_BUILD_CODEGEN=OFF -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-26 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

cmake --build .
```

When I build grpc to static link library,An error occurs when the progress reaches 91%:

```
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro grpc %  cmake --build .
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target address_sorting
[  0%] Built target address_sorting
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target gpr
[  2%] Built target gpr
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target c-ares
[  5%] Built target c-ares
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target zlibstatic
[  6%] Built target zlibstatic
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target grpc
[ 26%] Built target grpc
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target grpc_cronet
[ 44%] Built target grpc_cronet
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target grpc_unsecure
[ 59%] Built target grpc_unsecure
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target libprotobuf
[ 64%] Built target libprotobuf
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target grpc++
[ 67%] Built target grpc++
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target grpc++_cronet
[ 83%] Built target grpc++_cronet
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target grpc++_unsecure
[ 85%] Built target grpc++_unsecure
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target libprotoc
[ 90%] Built target libprotoc
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target grpc_plugin_support
[ 91%] Built target grpc_plugin_support
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target grpc_csharp_ext
[ 91%] Linking CXX shared library libgrpc_csharp_ext.so
ld: error: undefined symbol: X509_STORE_new
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:787 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:787)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(tsi_ssl_root_certs_store_create(char const*)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: X509_STORE_free
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:797 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:797)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(tsi_ssl_root_certs_store_create(char const*)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:806 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:806)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(tsi_ssl_root_certs_store_destroy(tsi_ssl_root_certs_store*)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: BIO_new_mem_buf
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:593 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:593)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:519 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:519)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(populate_ssl_context(ssl_ctx_st*, tsi_ssl_pem_key_cert_pair const*, char const*)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:563 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:563)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(populate_ssl_context(ssl_ctx_st*, tsi_ssl_pem_key_cert_pair const*, char const*)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced 1 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_sk_new_null
>>> referenced by x509.h:77 (/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include/openssl/x509.h:77)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:602 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:602)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:602 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:602)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:602 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:602)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced 2 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: X509_free
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:632 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:632)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:632 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:632)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:641 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:641)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced 4 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: X509_get_subject_name
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:608 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:608)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:266 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:266)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(peer_from_x509(x509_st*, int, tsi_peer*)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: X509_NAME_dup
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:614 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:614)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_sk_push
>>> referenced by x509.h:77 (/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include/openssl/x509.h:77)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: ERR_clear_error
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:622 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:622)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:622 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:622)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:604 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:604)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced 2 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: X509_STORE_add_cert
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:623 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:623)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:623 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:623)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: ERR_get_error
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:624 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:624)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:624 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:624)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:1237 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1237)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(ssl_handshaker_next(tsi_handshaker*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char const**, unsigned int*, tsi_handshaker_result**, void (*)(tsi_result, void*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, tsi_handshaker_result*), void*)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced 2 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_sk_pop_free
>>> referenced by x509.h:77 (/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include/openssl/x509.h:77)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by x509v3.h:166 (/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include/openssl/x509v3.h:166)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(peer_from_x509(x509_st*, int, tsi_peer*)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: BIO_free
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:648 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:648)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:0 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:0)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(create_tsi_ssl_handshaker(ssl_ctx_st*, int, char const*, tsi_ssl_handshaker_factory*, tsi_handshaker**)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:552 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:552)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(populate_ssl_context(ssl_ctx_st*, tsi_ssl_pem_key_cert_pair const*, char const*)) in archive libgrpc.a
>>> referenced 10 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: X509_NAME_free
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:0 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:0)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(x509_store_load_certs(x509_store_st*, char const*, unsigned int, stack_st_X509_NAME**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: SSL_new
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:1340 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1340)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(create_tsi_ssl_handshaker(ssl_ctx_st*, int, char const*, tsi_ssl_handshaker_factory*, tsi_handshaker**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: SSL_set_info_callback
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:1352 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1352)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(create_tsi_ssl_handshaker(ssl_ctx_st*, int, char const*, tsi_ssl_handshaker_factory*, tsi_handshaker**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: BIO_new_bio_pair
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:1354 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1354)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(create_tsi_ssl_handshaker(ssl_ctx_st*, int, char const*, tsi_ssl_handshaker_factory*, tsi_handshaker**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: SSL_set_bio
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:1359 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1359)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(create_tsi_ssl_handshaker(ssl_ctx_st*, int, char const*, tsi_ssl_handshaker_factory*, tsi_handshaker**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: undefined symbol: SSL_set_connect_state
>>> referenced by ssl_transport_security.cc:1362 (src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1362)
>>>               ssl_transport_security.cc.o:(create_tsi_ssl_handshaker(ssl_ctx_st*, int, char const*, tsi_ssl_handshaker_factory*, tsi_handshaker**)) in archive libgrpc.a

ld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use -error-limit=0 to see all errors)
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libgrpc_csharp_ext.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/grpc_csharp_ext.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
mindgood@minds-MacBook-Pro grpc %
```

How to solve this error? Please help me. Or how to compile grpc to static link library  on macOS?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved by myself,the answer is at https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1789